# Delete button uitableview cell; a bit jumpy?

Tags: iphone, ios

When i set a table into editing mode and try to delete a cell, i am having issues with the "delete" button playing hide and see :)

When i tap on the "minus" symbol, the delete button pops in but seems to be a bit jumpy, have to try a few times to get an actual tap on the delete button. 
Am not sure what the reason is

Any suggestsions?

p.s: I have edited this question. Previously it was in regard to swipe and delete, but i believe the problem is also with the regular delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show delete button set tableView.editing property to YES and implement delegate's editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath method and return appropriate editing style (None, Insert or delete) for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Im just shooting in the dark as i have'nt seen your code.

if you are detecting swipe through the old `touchesBegan: withEvent:` `touchesMoved:withEvent:` approach,this might happen as you are touching the cell.

With the new `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` in iOS 4.0, you could handle the swipe so easily.

IMHO.add a member variable to your UITableView subclass as `BOOL isDeleteButtonVisible` and use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to detect the swipe,then in the make the button visible and set the member variable.

In the `touchesBegan: withEvent:` method,check the button visibility by checking the `isDeleteButtonVisible` member variable and hide it if it is visible.

Im just giving you some hints.

Comment: thanks aji - interesting idea; but it even happens when i delete without swipe - i mean, set the table to editing mode, click on the small "-" symbol, then the delete button appears and starts behaving the same - "playing hard to get" :P

Comment: I think you should really need to check your touch handling code part.

Comment: But if i am using the typical table editing mode, no swipe delete, its still the same problem. I don't think there is an touch handling when setting the table to edit mode and deleting the record; right?

Comment: Im not sure about that,may be you should provide some of your code on pastie or something..

Comment: code? its just setting the table to editing mode table.editingMode=YES; that's about it. Swipe delete is automatically activated with IOS4 i suppose. But as i mentioned previously i am happy if i could get the regular delete to work (setting edit mode - tap the minus symbol - then press delete without having to play hide and seek with it)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this on an actual device? I was thinking the same about my tableview. It was running in the simulator and it was really difficult to do the right gesture or to hit the button.

But on the device it felt like it should be.

Comment: yes i have tried it on a real device, in fact some ad-hoc testers too. same problem.